# jQuery Mobile 元のページに戻る処理

Tags: jquery-mobile

基本的な質問で、申し訳ありません。

jQuery Mobileを使用したページで「index.html, hoge.html」があり、画面遷移としては、index.htmi→hoge.html→index.htmlとします。

まずindex.htmlのdata-role="page"が読み込まれ、次に画面遷移され、hoge.htmlのdata-role="page"のDOMが追加されるのはわかります。

そのあと、リンクをクリックして、index.htmlに戻る際、再度index.htmlのDOMが追加され、スタイル崩れが発生してしまっています。

過去に閲覧したページのDOMを追加しないように制御するには、どうしたらよいでしょうか？その他にも対処方法があるのでしょうか？

Comment: PCで開発しているときに使用しているブラウザはChromeです（正式には、Android Chrome/iPhone Safariで動作できればOKです）。

Comment: 質問への追記は、質問文下の「編集」から自由にできますのでお試しください :)

Comment: 質問文に書かれている現象を再現可能なコードを追記していただけませんか？